# How does Redphone encryption work?

Tags: security, privacy

[Redphone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.redphone&hl=en) is known for providing encryption for end-to-end calls. I am eager to know how it protects our privacy from telecom companies.

How does it secure our call and text and protect our privacy from even telecom companies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses a Protocol called zrpt to encrypt your voice which then is transfered via voice over ip.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZRTP